# Can not call Alibaba Cloud API

Tags: api-gateway, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ros

I am using Alibaba Cloud. I have [followed](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/43615.htm?spm=a3c0i.o43611en.b99.62.12f15cdebTLJTX) the document to use API to query a group.

For example: I use `http://apigateway.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com?Action=DescribeApiGroup
&GroupId=xxx&AccessKeyId=xxx`.

I got the error `InvalidVersion: Specified parameter Version is not valid.`

If you faced this error, please help me how to call the API. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The APIs of the API Gateway are called by sending HTTP GET requests **with corresponding request parameters included in the requests according to the interface instructions**. The system returns processing results according to the request processing status.

The problem with your query is that the server is expecting more parameters and you are only passing Action, GroupId and AccessKeyId. And when the server is not finding the Version parameter in your query, it is throwing the `InvalidVersion` error.

Here is a list of **required parameters** that you are missing in your request:

- Version
- Signature
- SignatureMethod
- SignatureNonce
- SignatureVersion
- TimeStamp

An example of a valid request would be:

```
https://apigateway.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/?Format=xml
&Version=2016-07-14
&Signature=Pc5WB8gokVn0xfeu%2FZV%2BiNM1dgI%3D
&SignatureMethod=HMACSHA1
&SignatureNonce=15215528852396
&SignatureVersion=1.0
&AccessKeyId=key-test
&TimeStamp=2016-08-08T08:00:00Z
```

However, the format parameter is not strictly required. For more information on the request parameters, you can visit https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/43597.htm

Comment: This answer is correct. For each Alibaba REST API, there are two sets of parameters. API Parameters that are specific to the service request and "Public" parameters that are required for all REST API calls. Both sets of parameters are required. The answer above shows the Public parameters.